# Google-map does not reload - Ionic2 and 3

Tags: cordova, google-maps, ionic2, ionic3

I am working on a ionic3 app which contains 5 pages and a navigation-drawer.
From navigation drawer, We can load any page as root page.

One of the page,name GoogleMapPage, contains a google-map. The map is loading and working properly. But I am having a strange issue.

Suppose the current root page is GoogleMapPage and if I set this page again as root page, the map doesn't load.

Now If I set another page as root page and come back to GoogleMapPage, the map does load.

Why does this thing happening? Why loading the same page doesn't load the map?

Updated:
I am using cordova-plugin-googlemaps  for google map. And following is the code to load the map:

```
 loadMap() {

    let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');

    this.map = this.googleMaps.create(element);

    // listen to MAP_READY event
    this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(() => {
      console.log('Map is ready!');   
    });   }
```

I am calling the `loadMap` method in `ionViewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Are you using the cordova-plugin-googlemaps or the javascript library? Could you add the code where you load/initialize the map?

Comment: @sebaferreras Yes I am using the cordova-plugin-googlemaps plugin. I have also added code to load map.

Comment: And when do you call that `loadMap()` method?

Comment: in ionViewDidLoad  method

Comment: could you try by using `ionViewDidEnter` instead? Since Ionic pages are cached, the issue may be related to the `ionViewDidLoad` not being fired when the page has been load already

Comment: I have tried in ionViewWillEnter, ionViewDidEnter and also ngAfterViewInit but same behaviour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147434/discussion-between-rohit-gupta-and-sebaferreras).